# Dart abstract private method

Tags: dart

How can I have an abstract private method in dart?

```dart
// person.dart
abstract class Person{
  void _walk();  //Abstract Method
  void _talk();  //Abstract Method
}
```

```dart
// jay.dart
import "person.dart";
class Jay extends Person{
  @override
  void _walk() {
    print("Jay can walk");
  }
 @override
  void _talk() {
    print("Jay can talk");
  }
}
```

I want to hide `_walk` and `_talk`  from `Jay` instance

Comment: A private abstract method doesn't make any sense.  Private methods in the abstract base class are callable only by the abstract base class's library, and if they're abstract they have no implementation, so there's no point in calling them at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `protected` method , Your statement is wrong , if you define both class in same file , or use `library` you can override private method

Comment: What part is wrong?  I specifically said that a private method is callable by the class's *library*.  The "library" is usually a file but can be encompass other files with the `library` keyword.  Anyway, a `_` prefix makes things private, not protected.  Dart doesn't have a native notion of protected methods; you instead must make them public and use the `@protected` annotation.  But if you want them to be protected, then you *want* derived classes to override them, so it still doesn't make sense.  Are you saying that you want only derived classes in your library to override those methods?

Comment: Yes you are right, Sorry for my mistake ,  Are you saying that you want only derived classes in your library to override those methods : YES!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) provides a [`@visibleForOverriding`](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/visibleForOverriding-constant.html) annotation that might do what you want.  Note that violating it will generate only an analysis warning, and it won't be enforced at runtime.

Personally I think that putting things that are meant to be private in the abstract base class is a bad idea since they shouldn't be part of the interface.  Consider instead doing:

```dart
abstract class Person {
  ...
}

abstract class _Person extends Person {
  void walk();
  void talk();
}
```

and now your library can internally derive classes from `_Person` and use `walk` and `talk`, and they won't be exposed at all to external consumers of your library.

Answer (score 0):

Not abstract class but if you want to achieve inherit methods for just spesific classes, then you can use mixins;

```
mixin MixinName on ClassOne, ClassTwo {
   void function() {}
}
```

on ClassOne file;

ClassOne with MixinName

with this way, class one access the function().

I know, it is not your questions answer but it maybe helpful for someone who want to succed smilar problem.