# How to override private fields and methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

I've found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620495/dart-abstract-private-method), but I cannot comment it. So I started this thread.
I want to make an abstract database class, which is implemented by a real database classes like postgresdb class. And I want to make private fields and abstract methods in an abstract db class to remain private in childs. Cause there is no any sense in making password and other stuff public.
I can make it in one file, but is there any ways to make it in different files? Cause classes are quite big. One of the commentators advised to use library keyword. But in doesn't work, at least in Intellij IDEA. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

For example it's a base class:

```
abstract class DBSQL {
  final _initDBFilePath = '.';

  final String _address;
  final int _port;
  final String _dbname;
  final String _username;
  final String _password;
}
```

This is a child class:

```
class DBPostgres implements DBSQL {

  @override
  final String _id;

  @override
  final String _initDBFilePath = 'path-to-sql.sql';

  @override
  final String _address;
  @override
  final int _port;
  @override
  final String _dbname;
  @override
  final String _username;
  @override
  final String _password;

  DBPostgres(
      {@required address,
      @required port,
      @required dbname,
      @required username,
      @required password})
      : _address = address,
        _port = port,
        _dbname = dbname,
        _username = username,
        _password = password,
        _id = '$address:$port/$dbname';
}
```

IDEA wants me to remove overrides. I tryied to use @visibleForOverride from meta package, but doesn't work too.

I use Dart 2.12.0-224.0.dev with meta-1.3.0 on Win10 x64.
I know that in Java there is no such a problem. You can override everything in the ancestor class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes are in different libraries, then you *cannot* override private members.

The member are *private*, which means that you can't see them at all from a different library, and therefore you also can't override them.

You're trying to declare other fields with the same names, but the way library privacy in Dart works, that's actually going to be different names because library private names are unique to the library they are in. So, your variables have different names than the original, and code trying to access the original's variables won't see yours.

You have to be in the same library for this to work. Then there should be no problem.

Comment: Yes, I've seen such an explanation. But, as I said, I tryied to add library keyword with the same name to all DB files like "library db;", but it didn't worked for me. Only putting all the DB code into one file works. So I don't understand - is it a bug or it works as it should.

Comment: That is working as intended. The library name has no effect, other than give the library a name for display. The thing that determines the identity of a library is the URL it's being referenced by. (Which is also why using two different URLs to refer to the same file, for example different casing on Windows, makes the compiler treat it as two different libraries).

Comment: It's not working. As I understand you, you mean that if I write the same library name in the head of every of two file, I must not import each other from within of each other. Because importing a file means another library. But it doesn't work. There just a missing import appears. One library of two files doesn't concatenate them.

Comment: No, I'm saying you must put the two classes in the same library *file*. At most into [*part* files](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package) of the same library. Ignore library names, they mean nothing.

Comment: Ok, thx, I tryied to use "library" with "part" and "part of". It works. I didn't even know about "part" keywords. And I thought that (like in java), project's files' scope is automatically united, no metter how much files do you use. It would be better if you write the code, that works. In that case I wouldn't have so much questions.